# PHP check for string inside string

Tags: php

I have variable x and I want to see if it contains a string like `hs` even though the value may be `cug hs ib ap`. Can anybody help me figure this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
<?php
  $x  = 'cug hs ib';
  $y = strstr($x, 'hs');
  echo $y; 
?>
```

Update:
Better user [strpos](http://php.net/strpos)

```
<?php
  $x  = 'cug hs ib';
  $y = strpos($x, 'hs');
  if($y === false)
      // Not a substring
  else
      // Substring

?>
```

Comment: what is the difference between strstr + strpos?

Comment: strstr returns the string starting from the first occurrence while strpos returns number (the position) of the substring

Comment: @JosephTorraca: `strstr` finds the first occurrence of a substring within a string, returning the string from that index unless the third parameter is set to `true`. `strpos` returns the index of the first character of the first occurrence of a substring or false if not found.

Comment: @Michael Robinson: Good explanation, but don't forget that third parameter in strstr is for PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strpos($big_string, $sub_string) !== false)
{
    // $big_string contains $sub_string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
    echo "the string '{$needle}' was found within '{$haystack}'";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `substr_count` .. http://php.net/substr_count or `strpos`, http://php.net/strpos

Comment: thanks for providing the link, I tried google'ing it and found nothing

Answer (score 1):

Either strpos() or stripos() (depending on whether you're interested in case sensitivity).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php